# How to gracefully shutdown the spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to gracefully start and shutdown the spring boot application using a script . Is there any other way to do it except using an actuator module in the application. Currently i have to stop the spring boot process manually in the task manager.

Comment: do you want to handle the stop of the application or should the application stop after finishing the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to gracefully shutdown embeded jetty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347144/how-to-gracefully-shutdown-embeded-jetty)

Comment: How do you start your app exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to shutdown a Spring Boot Application in a correct way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547532/how-to-shutdown-a-spring-boot-application-in-a-correct-way)

Comment: try this for graceful starting and stopping of the applications via shell script and pid file: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547532/how-to-shutdown-a-spring-boot-application-in-a-correct-way/51426095#51426095

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately the spring boot application spins off a java process which needs to be killed. At present you are killing it manually.

You have a few options:

1. You can use `SpringApplication.exit(ApplicationContext, ExitCodeGenerator...)`  method.
2. If your application is not a long running application then do you have some exit point where your application should stop. At that point you can `System.exit(0)`
3. You can use external manager tools, for example on unix you can use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/), here is a [blog](http://patrickgrimard.com/2014/06/06/bootiful-spring-apps-with-supervisor/) you can read about this.
4. `SpringApplication.run` gives you `ApplicationContext` which you can close.

Comment: try this for graceful starting and stopping of the applications via shell script and pid file: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547532/how-to-shutdown-a-spring-boot-application-in-a-correct-way/51426095#51426095